# Syntax error in onClick()

Tags: android, eclipse, syntax

ok so now what i got is this as shown below . cant seem to solve it still . a little help please for android developer eclipse application for my final year project .wacthed alot of videos about it on youtube and google but non manage to help fixed the syntax error i've got here .

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Category extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    };
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        };
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: Strive for consistent use of indentation. Then when you do something wrong like this, it will look wrong.

Comment: Please look at my solution it may solve your issue. If solved please tick as accepted..

Comment: we are not here to fix your syntax errors...

Comment: now everything is fixed . just that when i click clean . theres an " ! " make on the left side of the bar saying

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodInvocation
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody

Answer (score 1):

Check your onClick() methods bro...

```
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
         {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
         }); // This was missing.

            Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

            switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
              {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hope this solves your issue... If not state what you are trying to do clearly... And don't worry if the guys are a bit hard on your questions... If you are a beginner slidenerd tutorials will really help you a lot. All the best

Answer (score 0):

Take the semicolon away at the end of this inner onClick method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
    startActivity(intent);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
    startActivity(intent);
};
```

with

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: same thing is there again, look at

    Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2); 
 
    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
 
            @Override 
        public void onClick(View v) { 
            Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class); 
            startActivity(intent); 
 
        }; 

Remove last Semicolon here

Answer (score 0):

You did not close the scope properly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.lge.cptool.R;

public class Category extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);

        Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

                switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
                        startActivity(intent);

                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
                // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
                // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
                int id = item.getItemId();
                if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                    return true;
                }
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Nothing more than syntax error. Use this

```
public class Category extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_category);


    Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cake.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });




    Button switchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    switchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Category.this, Cookie.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.category, menu);
    return true;
 }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
// automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
// as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
int id = item.getItemId();
if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Comment: Replace your whole class with this.

Comment: hi i did what you posted but now my setOnClickListener , OnClickListener and onClick(View v) has error

Comment: Can you post that error? Maybe you will have to import onclicklistener by hovering your mouse pointer on the error line and selecting the import onclicklistener.